# Add class to div using Rangy Library

Tags: jquery, html, rangy

I am using the rangy library to add a class to the selected text, but instead of adding a class to the `<span>` I would like to add it to the existing `<div>` tags in the selection.

How do I go about adding it to the div.
Below is the code that I use to add the class.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('frame')
var sel = rangy.getSelection(elem)
var iframeWin = rangy.dom.getIframeWindow(elem);
var boldRedApplier = rangy.createClassApplier("boldRed")
boldRedApplier.applyToSelection(iframeWin)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the example [**HERE**](https://github.com/timdown/rangy/blob/master/demos/position.html#L118):

```
var button = document.createElement("input");
button.type = "button";
button.unselectable = true;
button.className = "unselectable"; // This is the line that adds the class
```

**EDIT:**

To add a class to an existing element, try the below:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('frame');
elem.className = "someclassname";
```

Comment: thanks for the reply alexander but i need to add class to the existing 'divs' in the selection instead of adding new div.